# Access 2010 - optimization a query

Tags: ms-access

Can help me please to optimize this query in database (access 2010), this query to work very slowly (if use it in a big table):

```
SELECT П1.Code, П1.Field, П1.Number, П1.Data, [П1].[Number]-(select П3.Number from [Table] as П3 
    where П3.Field = П1.Field                                                            
    and П3.Data = (select Max(Data)                                                                           
    from [Table] as П2                                                                           
    where П2.Field = П1.Field and П1.Data > П2.Data)) AS Difference
FROM [Table] AS П1
ORDER BY П1.Field, П1.Data;
```

I'm attach a picture: http://s33.postimg.org/otm859xtb/Table_query.png

Link in the database: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06711692152703646964

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
SELECT t.Code,t.Field,t.Number,t.Data,t.Number-tm.LastNumber AS Difference
FROM [Table] AS t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t.Field,t.Number AS LastNumber
  FROM [Table] AS t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Field,MAX(Data) AS MaxData
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY Field
    ) AS tm ON tm.Field=t.Field AND tm.MaxData=t.Data
  ) AS tm ON tm.Field=t.Field
```

The sub-selects can give you some issues with formatting in Access, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

PLease try this one, just the same like Kevin ))

```
SELECT Table.Code, Table.Field, Table.Number, Table.Data, [Table].[Number]-[t1].[number] AS Difference
FROM 
(SELECT Table.Code, Table.Field, Table.Number, Table.Data
FROM [Table] INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Table.Field, Max(Table.Data) AS MaxOfData
FROM [Table] GROUP BY Table.Field) AS t2 ON (t2.MaxOfData = Table.Data) AND
(Table.Field = t2.Field)) AS t1 INNER JOIN [Table] ON t1.Field = Table.Field;
```